# How to disable addAll and removeALL button in <rich:picklist> 4.1

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I want removeAll and addAll need to be disable .
i tried

```
'
 .rich-picklist-control-removeall 
 {
 display:none;
 }
'
```

above one not working

'
`removeAllvisible="false"'` --- no such attribute in 4.1

please suggest

Comment: Try using Jquery If you have Idea about Jquery `$('div[id~="removeall"]').remove()`

Answer (score 1):

```
.rf-pick-add-all,
.rf-pick-rem-all {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but .rf-pick-rem-all is superceded by .rf-pick-btn { display: inline-block; }

Comment: @april26 Make sure that your CSS rules are loaded after RichFaces rules, so in case of same weight - your rule is used. Alternative: modify the selector so it has bigger weight (e.g. .rf-pick-btn.rf-pick-add-all { display: none; } ). Even if you prefer the alternative, I think order of loading stylesheets should be changed anyways: library's rules first, then your custom rules)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
.ui-picklist button[icon="fa-angle-double-left"] {
  display: none !important;
}

.ui-picklist button[icon="fa-angle-double-right"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

´.rf-pick-add-all, 
.rf-pick-rem-all {
    display: none !important;
}`